# What is the best way of combining two uints into an int for overridding GetHashCode()?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class where I have overridden Equals based on two uint values. Because I have overridden Equals I need to override GetHashCode.

The one uint value represents an id that should never have a duplicate. It will not necessarily be an auto-incrementing int value but should be in most cases. The second uint value represents a type field for the object.

Using only the ID field should be enough. But it might be a little restrictive in some cases which is why i wanted to combine the ID and the type.

I thought of adding the two numbers together and then combining the high order bits with the lower order bits using XOR.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can the `uint ID` field genuinely occupy the whole range of `uint`?

Comment: *But it might be a little restrictive in some cases* - Can you explain a little more about what the cases are where using only the ID field is too restrictive for you?

Comment: If I have multiple sessions open to different entities then the same ID can be used. The session however should be of no concern to my class so I don't want to take it into account because then I have leaky implementations. So I thought that the chance that an object across different sessions has the exact same type and ID is very slim. But perhaps I should not care. They can write custom compartors to take that into account. Perhaps ID is all I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash code is only used to distribute items in hash based collections like a `Dictionary`, so the hash code should ideally produce as few collisions as possible.

The minimum requirement is however only that the hash code should always be the same for any given set of values. Therefore even this is a valid hash code algorithm:

```
public int GetHashCode() {
  return 1;
}
```

Eventhough it gives a horrible distribution, it's still functional.

If you want to use both the Id and Type in the hash code, you can just xor them together:

```
public int GetHashCode() {
  return (int)Id ^ (int)Type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that there will never (or rarely) be a duplicate `id` then you can just use that.

But in general to get a good HashCode for two ints `a` and `b` you can choose a small prime `p` and calculate `a + p * b`.

Comment: I was just worried about overflows seeing as some of the types have uint values at the very end of the uint range.

Comment: @uriDium: By default overflow is ignored (unchecked). It doesn't matter here if there is overflow - the hash code will still be usable even when overflow occurs.